# Display nested objects properties in next (new) line

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

I have array of objects, where there are subojects (nested objects). Whole structure is looking similar to this (all subobjects have same labels, only values are different):

```
           var arr = [
                obj0 = {

                    subObj0: {
                        name: "John",
                        lastName: "Doe",
                        age: 50,
                        nick: "JD",
                        phone: 123456
                    },
                    subObj1: {
                        name: "Jane",
                        lastName: "Dee",
                        age: 30,
                        nick: "lady",
                        phone: 654098
                    },
                    subObj2: {
                        name: "Ash",
                        lastName: "Bash",
                        age: 33,
                        nick: "asdB",
                        phone: 987123
                    }
                },
                obj1 = {
                    subObj0: {
                        name: "Asd",
                        lastName: "Dsa",
                        age: 10,
                        nick: "none",
                        phone: 12
                    },
                    subObj1: {
                        name: "Ivy",
                        lastName: "Mash",
                        age: 3,
                        nick: "IvMash",
                        phone: 9823
                    }

                }

            ];
```

I was trying to display these subobjects in console like this:

```
for (index in arr)
{
    for (index2 in arr[index])
    {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arr[index][index2],null,4));
    }
}
```

, it gave me output with tree of these objects and subobjects.

**How to** display it in console as **every subobject is in new line**, like below?

[image]

So without commas and double quotes, only **"label: value"** form.

Comment: Are you intentionally creating global variables (`obj0`, `obj1`)?

Comment: No, i created this array of object of subobjects in loop earlier, i called it here like (obj0, obj1) cause JavaScript called them like that dynamically.

Comment: Why don't you create the string representation within the same loop you're creating the array? `JSON.stringify` converts its first argument to JSON data format, it doesn't create arbitrary formatting. Notice also, that `obj0` and `obj1` are not a part of the array, they are just variables, and globals, if you haven't declared them in a function.

Comment: "Why don't you create the string representation within the same loop you're creating the array? " It's possible, but difficult for me. I wanted to outpu all after i joined objects together. I created those objects like **labels** where from other array and **values** were from other - i connected them in one array of subobjects.

Comment: You can't create the array in your example dynamically. Please show the loop, we'll see what we can do. Definitely you can't achieve this by `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kXeNP2TR Products are loaded from file http://pastebin.com/teBRXBTb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few `replace()` should do it. Click the run button to see the results.

```js
var arr = [
    {
        subObj0: {
            name: "John",
            lastName: "Doe",
            age: 50,
            nick: "JD",
            phone: 123456
        },
        subObj1: {
            name: "Jane",
            lastName: "Dee",
            age: 30,
            nick: "lady",
            phone: 654098
        },
        subObj2: {
            name: "Ash",
            lastName: "Bash",
            age: 33,
            nick: "asdB",
            phone: 987123
        }
    },
    {
        subObj0: {
            name: "Asd",
            lastName: "Dsa",
            age: 10,
            nick: "none",
            phone: 12
        },
        subObj1: {
            name: "Ivy",
            lastName: "Mash",
            age: 3,
            nick: "IvMash",
            phone: 9823
        }

    }

];

var output = [];
arr.forEach(function (obj, i) {
    output.push('obj' + i + ':');
    for (var key in obj) {
        var value = obj[key];
        var str = JSON.stringify(value)
            .replace(/[{}"]/g, '') // remove {} and "
            .replace(/[,]/g, '\t') // replace commas by tabulations
            .replace(/:/g, ': ');  // add a nice space after :
        output.push(key + ': ' + str);
    }
})

output = output.join('\n');
console.log(output);
document.write('<pre>' + output + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks! I added also `.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'')` to remove square braces.

Comment: I found more semantic (i think) way to output each subobject in separate line with my type of objects structure http://pastebin.com/ptKs4ize
. Where **products** are each array index first proper object. Cause eventually my array elements has structure like this http://imgur.com/dnna9tV. So outer loop iterates through array (length of 3), then i have to go to first object of 'products' and then iterate through its length, and inside there by inner (second) loop i can output each subobject.